# Cannot use instance, after created instance. Gettting error User.find is not a function when try to get documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using nodejs with expressjs framework with MongoDB. In mongoose have created instance as **var User = new userModel(data).** Here is my model **user.js**

```
const userModel = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports.listUser = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();   
    var User= new userModel();
    User.find({}, function (err, list) {
        if (err) {           
            deferred.resolve({status: 'error'});
        } else {
            deferred.resolve({ status: 'ok', list: list});
        }      
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: you can try userModel instead of User.find. I think it works.

Comment: When I try to get documents getting error like "User.find is not a function"

Comment: Try to use userModel.find(...)

Comment: Yes. It's working fine.

Comment: You can userModel to find and whenever you want to insert data then you can user var user = new userModel({...userModelFields}) to insert data

Comment: May I know differrence and why can't I use var User = new userModel(); User.find like this

Comment: you can view this to refine your concepts. https://coursework.vschool.io/mongoose-crud/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166218/discussion-between-indianv-and-zeeshan-afzal-satti).

Answer (score 0):

So you just mixed things a little bit. As can be seen in the [Mongoose: Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) documentation, you need to use a model (`userModel` in your case) for accessing the different [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations.

In order to create a User document, you can use the syntax as you did, but must supply the properties aswell.

```
var User = new userModel({
     name: 'Indianv',
     website: 'stackoverflow.com',
     .......
});
```

Then, in order to find documents within the User collection, you should use:

```
userModel.find({ name: 'Indianv' }, function(err, userDoc) {
     if(!err) {
          .....
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well according to `mongoose` [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) you should follow the following procedure to perform `find` or other db operations

```
var Person= require('mongoose').model('Person');
exports.getContactList = (req, res) => {
Person.find({}, {}, { limit: 20 }, (error, list) => {
if (error)
  res.send(error)
res.json(list)
});

}
```

Getting all of the documents at once may not be a wise idea, so you can apply `limit` on your query and then perform pagination to get other related documents